# Reading Values from GET method for WEB API

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to get a list of items in WebAPI

The ajax methods looks like this

```
       $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'api/values',
            data: JSON.stringify({ pageNo: pageNo + 1, pageSize: pageSize }), 
            contentType: 'application/json'
       });
```

In the values controller I am not able to get the values.

my controller looks like this.

```
    public IEnumerable<string> Get([FromURI] pagingInfo)
    {   
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }
```

What is the correct standard. Is the above standard correct 
or should put the pageno and pagesize in url and create an another route.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, it is not recommended (or even banned) to send body via GET, just only query string is valid:

Removing method `JSON.stringify`, your ajax call should be:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/api/values",
    data: { pageNo: 1, pageSize: 2 },
    success: function (data) {
    }
});
```

It will automatically convert to query string, if using `JSON.stringify`, you will get JSON notation in query string and make it wrong. If you take a look on Fiddler, using `JSON.stringify`, the URL is like:

```
/api/values?{%22PageNo%22:1,%22PageSize%22:2}
```

And your Action is till:

```
public IEnumerable<string> Get([FromURI]PagingInfo pagingInfo)
{   
    return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
}
```

Comment: My confusion is, In web API we have a method called get. For example say products the route is api/products. if you want product 1 then the route looks like api/products/1 where 1 is the Id. Now say suppose for better scalability you want to get products paged. The url might look like api/products/1-25 where 1 is the page and 25 is the number of items. If sending the body is banned   what is the correct approach to this? if the api/products/1-25 is the correct way to declare then api/products/1 is going to fail because we dont know how to interpret it.